# Поиск и удаление строк

Tags: vbscript

Задача: удалить строку и все строки над ней, у которой есть в колонке слово "Дата"

То, что я делаю и должно работать, но не срабатывает.

```
nRow = 1
    fend = 0
    Do While (wb.Sheets(1).Cells(nRow, 1).Value <> "Дата" and fend = 0) 
           if inStr(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(nRow, 1).Value, "Дата")> 0 then
              fend = 1
              wb.Sheets(1).Rows("1:" & nRow).Delete            
           end if
           nRow = nRow + 1
        loop
```

Comment: То, что Вы описываете словами, в принципе не соответствует коду.

Comment: @Akina правда? Просто я хотел, чтобы сначала искало первое вхождение "Дата", а дальше удаляло всё, что выше. Что конкретно тут неправильно? Можете показать как будет верно.

Comment: *Что конкретно тут неправильно?* Вы ищете ячейку, которая содержит слово "Дата", но **не равно** "Дата" (т.е. есть ещё символы). И не понимаю необходимости наличия переменной `fend`, когда имеется оператор `Exit Do`... равно как и не понимаю сканирования по одной ячейке, когда есть `Range.Find`.

Comment: Можете подсказать как поправить? А то не совсем понимаю.

Comment: Вам надо описание задачи поправить. До полной однозначности. А то программа "будет делать то, что ты сказал, а не то, что ты хотел"...

Comment: А1="фигня" А2="Дата:сегодня" А3="дата" А4="Дата". Нужно удалить строки от 1 до ... ?

Comment: Нашёл такой поиск, но не совсем понимаю как тогда удалить все строки выше и ту, которую нашёл: `With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a300") 
    Set c = .Find("Дата", lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            c.Value = 5 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If 
End With`

Comment: Суть в том, что нам приходит файл, он ищет первое вхождение слова "Дата" и сразу же удаляет строку полностью и всё, что над ней. То, сколько будет выше строк - неизвестно и их нужно удалить, включая, той, где находится первое слово "Дата", поэтому и ищем первое вхождение.

Comment: Именно вхождение? не равенство? Регистр символов - неважен?

Comment: Именно вхождение, регистр важен. Вот у нас к примеру может быть файл, где слово "Дата" находится на 5 строке, а выше него пустые строки, нужно удалить его строку и те, которые выше. В конечном итоге удаляются 5 строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wb.Sheets(1).Rows("1:" & wb.Sheets(1).Columns(1).Find(What:="Дата", MatchCase:=True).Row).Delete
```

---

`Find(What:="Дата", MatchCase:=True)` ищет ячейку со словом "Дата" с учётом регистра на листе `wb.Sheets(1)` в колонке `Columns(1)` (т.е. в колонке A).

Найдя ячейку, берём номер её строки (`.Row`).

И формируем запрос на удаление строк вида `Rows("1:N").Delete`. Где N - тот самый полученный поиском номер строки.

Код предполагает гарантированное наличие в колонке 1 ячейки с искомым словом - при отсутствии будет ошибка. Если необходимо, её можно временно маскировать с помощью, например, `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Предполагается наличие ")"

Comment: @Blacit Или с ошибкой переписываешь, или не туда вставляешь. Эта строка - заменяет весь твой код. Только что проверил копипастом в Debug window, заменив `wb` на `ThisWorkbook` - как из пушки.

Comment: Понимаю, что всё заменяет, по количеству скобочек тоже всё верно. Никак понять не могу почему просит скобочку. Ладно, а весь эту строку прям под кодом, который вы прислали нужно вставлять? `Rows("1:N").Delete`

Comment: @Blacit Это происходит в VBA или в VBScript? в любом случае - ругается явно не на эту строку. "Сопля" где-то ещё по коду. Всё, что под строкой кода - просто пояснение, как оно работает. `Rows("1:N").Delete` никуда вставлять не нужно...